# How to programmatically control the persistence in redis

Tags: redis, jedis, spring-data-redis, data-persistence

I'm using redis with my spring boot application using jedis, spring-data-redis. I want to control the persistence mechanism of redis in the following way.

- In one case I want the data to be persisted into the dump file, so
  that on restart of redis server that data should be accessible.
- In second case I want to keep the data just into redis in-memory and
  accessible to the application till the redis server is running and
  should be discarded on redis server restart.

I've read the [redis data persistence](https://redis.io/topics/persistence) policies and it seems that it allows storing the data on some time intervals, but is there any way I can control the persistence only programmatically & not use the time interval based persistence mechanism

Answer (score 1):

I found solution to this issue. So the changes I made to control the persistence only programmatically are as below

- Comment all the **save lines** from redis configuration file.
  This will stop redis's default time/operations based persistence mechanism.
- Then call [save()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisServerCommands.html#save--) or [bgsave()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/RedisServerCommands.html#bgSave--) whenever you want to persist the data on disc.

So using the [RedisTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html) you can call

```
redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().save();
```

and this will persist the changes on disc.

For my requirement, I'm passing a `shouldPersist` flag to my repository methods to decide whether to persist the data or not. If the data is not persisted using `save` or `bgsave` it will be discarded on server restart. Which is what I want for some of my scenarios.